# Generate Excel File from a DataSet Spark Java API?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to generate an excel file  from my DataSet ?

SomeBody can guide me with a sample expression.

Comment: You can use Apache POI for this . It can create sheets and data rows that can be populated from the data in the DataSet

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work the magic for you. (Syntax is wrong but the idea can work)

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;


HSSFWorkbook new_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = new_workbook.createSheet(obj.getSheetName());
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row header = sheet.createRow(0);

// Assume there are data already in an array which contains all the header field names
for (int y = 0; y < len; y++) {
    header.createCell(y).setCellValue(fieldAr[y]);
}
```

Next, you can populate the sheet by iterating the data in the Dataset (I can't get into specifics on how this can be done for your case), but something like this can work

```
for (String key : keySet) {
    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
    List<Object> objArr = excel_data.get(key);
    int cellNum = 0;
    for (Object object : objArr) {
       Cell cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
}

FileOutputStream output_file = new FileOutputStream(new File(output)); //create XLS file
    new_workbook.write(output_file);//write converted XLS file to output stream
    output_file.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

val ds = Seq(1,2,3,4,5).toDS

ds.write.csv("/tmp/file") // give some hdfs or file system path

it will store the data into multiple files based on the number of partitions of a dataset.

- use hdfs merge command if we store the data in hdfs
- use cat command and redirect all the output to a single csv file 
       like cat *.csv >> final.csv

Comment: I'm using Spark Java API. The method write dosn't support any argument.